# binary tree preorder traversal prints only NULL

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

Written my first simple tree data structure using C. Preorder traversal is not printing any values, only prints null. Can't able to detect where is the issue is. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
} Node;
```

**New node creation**

```
Node* newNode(int key) {
    Node* new = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->data = key;
    new->left = NULL;
    new->right = NULL;

    return new;
}
```

**Insertion using recursion**

```
Node* insert(Node* node, int key) {
    if (node == NULL)
        return newNode(key);
    else if (node->data > key)
        node->left = insert(node->left, key);
    else if (node->data < key)
        node->right = insert(node->right, key);
    else 
        return (node);
}
```

**Didn't get expected output**

```
void preorder(Node* node) {
    if (node != NULL) {
        printf("%d ",node->data);
        preorder(node->left);
        preorder(node->right);
    }
}

int main() {
    //Thinking issue might be in below initialization.
    Node* root=NULL;
    root = insert(root,10);
    root = insert(root,20);
    root = insert(root,30);
    root = insert(root,40);
    root = insert(root,50);
    root = insert(root,60);
    root = insert(root,25);

    preorder(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably because you leak a whole bunch of memory by constantly overwriting your root.

Comment: Well, you don't assign key to the `data` of the node ;)

Comment: @StoryTeller How so? OP inserts a node - this may change the root. (For an unbalanced tree this happens only the first time, but anyhow it is saver to not assume it)

Comment: @Henry - This isn't a self balancing tree. Insertion should not modify the identity of the root. Especially if all it does is just return a pointer to the new node without attaching it to anything.

Comment: In fact, you don't return a value on every branch of `insert`. The behavior of your program is undefined...

Comment: yes i think your correct. @StoryTeller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to add the key value inside the new node ;)

Just add : `new->data = key;` to the newNode code

```
Node* newNode(int key)
{
    Node* new = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->data = key;
    new->left = NULL;
    new->right = NULL;
    return new;
}
```

For the moment, since `node->data` is not define `else if (node->data > key)` and `else if (node->data < key)` will have an undifined behavior.

**Edit** : By the way, be "carefull" when you go inside the 2 `else if` condition, you never return a node, then `root = insert(root,20);` will not work. You **need** to return a value in those case.

```
Node* insert(Node* node, int key)
{
    if (node==NULL)
        return newNode(key);
    else if (node->data > key)
        node->left = insert(node->left, key);
    else if (node->data < key)
        node->right = insert(node->right, key);

    return node;
}
```

This code should work (if you change also the newNode function )

Comment: thank you i missed it. still preorder traversal is not printing. prints only final value 25.

Comment: @Balaji I re-edited my code to add the final solution. Please, validate the solution if this work out.

Comment: @Balaji For information, it was only prints the last value since first time you create the node. Then affect "Null", then recreate it etc ..

Comment: yes, return statement has the mistake. thanks @kaldoran

Answer (score 2):

You have several errors in your insert function. It doesn't return a valid pointer on every branch, so your `root` cannot be asserted as pointing to a valid address if you assign the result to it. Always turn compiler warnings to as high a level as possible.

Even though an unbalanced BST is a recursive data structure, I suggest you resist the urge to implement its operations recursively. It may be simple to write, but not always easy to debug.

```
Node* insert(Node* root, int key)
{
  Node **link= &root;
  while(*link) {
    if((*link)->data > key) {
      link = &((*link)->left);
    } else {
      link = &((*link)->right);
    }
  }

  *link = newNode(key);
  return root;
}
```

Take a moment to appreciate the abstraction here. The code above implements indirection to find the point of addition. It always keeps track of the tree *link* that must be modified on addition. Once an empty link is found (`*link == NULL`), we can assign to it.

It also fixes another silent bug in your code, the addition of duplicate keys will also overwrite the root. I took the liberty of adding them to the right sub-tree as is common in certain implementations. But you may stop there instead and return `root` immediately.